# CSS menu right alignment issue

Tags: css, alignment

I'm experiencing an issue with my website ( http://goo.gl/Di4jX )
Issue: I can't get the menu aligned to the right (2% from the right side of the page). "I tried float: right" but when I do that the menu items are in the wrong order. Is there a way to fix this?
Many thanks for your help
Greg

Comment: Put the 'float: right' on your _#nav_ element, and remove the 'width' :)

Comment: In fact it also works without the float, but since it was aligned left in a very wide box it could never get to the far right

Comment: Thanks Neograph.
I tried your solution (you can see the result at this addresshttp://goo.gl/KwP9I ) but the issue is that now my menu appears verticaly and no longer horizontaly. Any idea?

Comment: It looks good in my browser, but then you do have to set a width. Since the width of your menu entries is always the same you could specify this in pixels. About 520px should be fine.

Comment: Thanks, I specified a width and now it looks OK on both safari and firefox - tks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works with this :

```
#nav {
    right: 2%;
    list-style: none;
    position: fixed;
    /* float: left; useless with position fixed*/
    top: 30px;
    /* width: 50%; */
}

#nav > li {
    display: inline-block;
    /* dirty hack for IE7 */
    *display: inline;
    *zoom: 1;
}
```

Comment: Wow, works great, thank a lot!
I've never seen #nav > li before, would you mind giving me some additional information about the rational behind this code?
Many thanks again!

Comment: The > operator means direct children, so it will set the style to the `<li>`s with a direct `#nav` parent. It's not very usefull in this case but I prefer my selectors to be specific, writing `#nav li` is to sketchy to me, *all `<li>`s in #nav* can make troubles, mostly with nested menus.  
Anyway, this code only works for IE7+.

Answer (score 1):

You can achevie it simply by reducing the right of container  or reduce the width of that ul

for example css:-

```
#nav {
    float: right;
    list-style: none outside none;
    position: fixed;
    right: 2%;
    top: 30px;
    width: 43%;
}
```

or

```
#nav {
    float: right;
    list-style: none outside none;
    position: fixed;
    right: -5%;
    top: 30px;
    width: 50%;
}
```

apply these style if it is acceptable for you.

Comment: Thanks Satya. I guess this would work but would need to adjust the width everytime I add/remove menu items, right? Neograph's solution seems more scalable.
Thanks for your help

Comment: Ya you are correct. one more trick was reverse the order of menu items and float them left. then no need to change any css and you can add or delete menu items whenever required without changing any styles

Comment: The float order issue was because the element which has got float first will be floated first and remaining will follow it.

Comment: Tks Satya, finally sorted that out!